# «Если что я кому надо дам нагоняя» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Как расставить запятые? Буду признательна за ответ!
Фраза встретилась в художественной книге онлайн-автора.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что в этом предложении, написанном в разговорном стиле, запятая должна быть одна:
*Если что, я кому надо дам нагоняя.*

• **Если (ежели) что** = если что случится, если произойдёт что-либо.
Можно считать "если что" усеченным придаточным (с пропуском глагола). Именно из-за этого в таких предложениях вместо запятой часто используется тире.

*Если что, я его на руках понесу* (Андрей Геласимов. Год обмана).
*Если что ― меня здесь положишь, с девочками* (Гузель Яхина. Зулейха открывает глаза).
*Если что — я буду все отрицать* (Александра Маринина. Ангелы на льду не выживают).
*Если что, я ударю фонариком* (Татьяна Толстая. Ураган над Нью-Йорком).

• **Кто надо** (похоже по использованию на *кто угодно*) — определенное лицо или лица. Сочетание употреблено в дательном падеже, запятой не требует.

*По окончании училища радеющая мать в своей народностаничной смекалистости сунула **кому надо** на лапу, чтоб ее чадо перевели в часть по месту жительства...* (Александр Плетнев. Цепкие лапы времени).

• **Дать нагоняя** — сделать строгое внушение, наказать, распечь (просторечие).
В литературном языке используется сочетание "дать нагоняй".

*Безобразие, ну я им сейчас **дам нагоняя**, пойдемте, что с ним разговаривать, — недовольно высказался Корсаков и быстрым шагом пошел к вагону* (Александр Бабин. Разведка и волчье золото).

[ЧТО](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)
[НАГОНЯЙ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/114334)

P. S. Январь. Беспразднично, зябко и многоодёжно...
Просто для поднятия настроения: [Ты заходи, **если что**...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrrhiU0YV7I)